# Autodiscover with EWS wont work properly depending on the running machine

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, autodiscovery

I have a really strange problem with EWS.
Given are two machines and two mailboxes, both on "outlook.de"
The first mailbox work well on both machines.
The second mailbox works only on one machine.
The "not working machine" is an Azure-Server.
I have trace turned on, the significant different is here:

```
- Exchange2016http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/2010/Autodiscover/Autodiscover/GetUserSettingshttps://autodiscover-s.outlook.com/autodiscover/xyz@outlook.de/autodiscover.svcxyz@outlook.deInternalEwsUrlExternalEwsUrl
- Non-textual response
```

The last line seems to be the problem. I my trace where all is good i have instead this line:

```
- Exchange2016http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/2010/Autodiscover/Autodiscover/GetUserSettingshttps://autodiscover-s.outlook.com/autodiscover/xyz@outlook.de/autodiscover.svcxyz@outlook.deInternalEwsUrlExternalEwsUrl
- http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/2010/Autodiscover/Autodiscover/GetUserSettingsResponse1520462818Exchange2015NoErrorNoErrorNo error.SettingIsNotAvailableUser setting 'InternalEwsUrl' is not available. InternalEwsUrlExternalEwsUrlhttps://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx
```

Can anyone help me? Greetings, Karsten.

Edit:

I have now changes the Traceflags to TraceFlags.ALL and i get a new errormessage on the azure-machine:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 UnauthorizedServer: Microsoft-IIS/10.0request-id: 582b6a62-0a91-b141-0d1f-5020513b87f7X-CalculatedBETarget: AM8P193MB0818.EURP193.PROD.OUTLOOK.COMX-BackEndHttpStatus: 401X-RUM-Validated: 1X-AutoDiscovery-Error: LiveIdBasicAuth:UnfamiliarLocation:<UNH:<PII.Email:4772S6F6CM4JPggVFliJiaSmB5cnUgdUio5W9+TgIDk=>><RequestId=35c6eb23-4ee4-40d6-9143-4f876e44baba><UIPH:<PII.IP:PdctkeGb4bWluvcpeq0QYJ/AOpGLVeDGFFBzApIXB2E=>><MissHrd<CACHEFAIL:UnfamiliarLocation><Tarpit><UserType:OutlookCom><AS:UnfamiliarLocation><Tid=84df9e7f-e9f6-40af-b435-aaaaaaaaaaaa><V1;X-DiagInfo: AM8P193MB0818X-BEServer: AM8P193MB0818X-Proxy-RoutingCorrectness: 1X-Proxy-BackendServerStatus: 401X-FirstHopCafeEFZ: AMSX-Powered-By: ASP.NETX-FEServer: AM8P189CA0017WWW-Authenticate: Basic Realm=""Date: Fri, 22 Oct 2021 08:20:37 GMT
```

This what happens on a machine where the code is working:

```
- HTTP/1.1 200 OKCache-Control: privateTransfer-Encoding: chunkedServer: Microsoft-IIS/10.0request-id: ae5b0660-6d71-28ee-937a-4a26a6845118Alt-Svc: h3=":443"X-CalculatedBETarget: AM8P193MB0818.EURP193.PROD.OUTLOOK.COMX-BackEndHttpStatus: 200Set-Cookie: EXOBasicAuth=compactTicket=t%3dGABEAgMAAAAMgAAADQAgn0vsl27aNrnrFIH%2fm2k3YrHvzZpmhyuOLATxVFd7XxAAAaeGp4SeGeSuHdOupCtUxi8k%252b%252bX%252bigSJQOFkIzYBZiXvWQevdWeOapdogX%2fcaiexm%252bQK6TTb1t8iVlANBJGjYWDwSXVcMNsB6iaUYY3st1oHzN5BS3HWZ2btm3YPxHu5vV5kWn95lsDiZGkvCUKSMrKwIEeL%2f4W1hytOqbELJvTCciBayhb20BU067p6LX%252bexWCK9XFtASLUDeJT%252bWOHy7r2eovuTizD1YhcEk4Vk0haRfAU1Lqggm%2f0HW34BsHHSP0LaID3G6Mob%252bZq6WHoh37QKlKKGQ8SrugTDywsRBmwoRQJpTM40HNfVnLgd671k19jv1%2fiHaOau%2fgMf%2fcrhocRAXsAEQH9vwMA%252beCAQVt7cmFbe3Jh6XcEAAoRIIAAEwBiNGl0LXBtQG91dGxvb2suZGUAWQAAH2I0aXQtcG0lb3V0bG9vay5kZUBwYXNzcG9ydC5jb20AAAACREUAAAAAAAAEBwIAAHL6VUAABkMABVBldHJhAAdNYW5hZ2VyAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA9xbqSO1omIIAAFt7cmFbIulhAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADwA4Ny4xNDkuMjM2LjEzNAACAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAc17TG4EmGRUAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADAA%253d%253d&key=b4it-pm%40outlook.de+microsoft.exchange.autodiscover+87.149.236.134+&signature=kEUNjyvSpkXD5AvVKNywd0PP+qyV3qKKr+9xGIp2mzBjwzULijmIdfzUTwLVjK7ptfhByCGbWQikkXm8MEFOApvUovVcX3agt78+kyYWYDaBUz4wWw9c9/xssH+f/q0Epc06HWggVp+I2aorTr+oQxfHc8plGP5SqKFT1cq1Xa79OpaRJE6gz/K051qVLAVuM1UaMoX7EkxmScauJXsBfyg/BHYXy45itnsOTLYlEIsvKCClm5PRl1iG+pk9Op55CqEcH3cyExtkfcFEkOIofqjuc7yw/UMKQWQdoHZi7n4NVUDfdoWamMwCAtD7o4xumGoxOokTEpHc/RmDiajBwQ==&puid=0003BFFD4180E0F9&expireTime=637705182350000000&membername=b4IT-PM%40outlook.de&flags=False&userType=OutlookCom&aliasVersion=1&authInstant=1634892635&issueInstant=1634892635&recoveryInstant=0&authData=F/PIHrVTHRGuMmwfJkyDYGGFitzgOMeStAFYPfrDK1EySgoCPyajJAiYRoqJIUTaTSY+dn/BBKJFr7ARtYOrTcrDJqnv0tvjHbe5arnHpGl43LeagFl970/rOtxQDZHDj6WYqKnCwAb6Chdm3DGyn3e/bTAgDqCkNGZxCohCl/BieLaVheMpXBC4nayKCH0ZN/rmk12/plDDiWvvH+GfBZfR5P0X2pbqriIWmiSMj+EB2u08M0FwBkzdaMgkcLY64uHmpq2wMPxtB0yQn5xQ+ljBuqJXKbCLzkta9JqC6bLv5vO+nDsNjGLqVBJdZ/+u0Tb4eIX13xlpUcWuXZjxrg==&tokenData=h/xhhGTUBn3YYdCzx84fSzBzgx9W+x19C7ZmJk8NKydkyrywsvHbAbSs2inKaTvqMvfSokh4LwVCxftkohfWwNgb6255mxZuivYnnMgComkzLDoUBiqTsbkDtz48FT/W5/0LwhztwxRuJaBv7i88cWtvj2HmkFkznmfDo2CW55tMfsMvcNfOMZnVFNjzNHd5Y8BUJlFeaddbxBZmZVi67HFqG2Njk8M9gE6egs7Xa0d6unZqaFCi1QJWlXMOuNVgnFEHxFJDKQ2+40Z3o41tEExY3FbMP/Ze4/7NEu1XdFz9rBHdesOor8OQmbo9KqeRXA7zJf+Vhuixe4qMlu3SVQ==&clientIp=255.255.255.255&cid=ed689882f716ea48&ageGroup=3; expires=Fri, 22-Oct-2021 16:50:35 GMT; path=/autodiscover; secure; HttpOnlyX-RUM-Validated: 1X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319X-DiagInfo: AM8P193MB0818X-BEServer: AM8P193MB0818X-Proxy-RoutingCorrectness: 1X-Proxy-BackendServerStatus: 200X-FirstHopCafeEFZ: DHRX-Powered-By: ASP.NETX-FEServer: AS9PR06CA0106Date: Fri, 22 Oct 2021 08:50:34 GMT
```

Is this helpful?

Comment: what does your code look like that URL https://autodiscover-s.outlook.com/autodiscover/xyz@outlook.de/autodiscover.svc doesn't look valid the email address should be part of it. Maybe try the EWSEditor https://github.com/dseph/EwsEditor/releases from the location its not working to confirm if its your code or a general issue

Comment: Good news: Both Mailboxes now working properly - without changing the code. I dont know whats happen. I didnt changed my test and i didnt changed any configuration on the azure-machine. Strange, but true.